# PHP subtracting values from the database

Tags: php, html

My code for the fetching of the two values is fine, and the subtracting those values are also fine. The problem is that some values that are going to subtract has comma's(,) and it will echo a wrong answer.

My Code:

```
<?php
    $a = $value['stall_rate'];
    $b = $value['payment'];
    $result = $a - $b;
    echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: replace the comma by a point for the subtracting ?

Comment: your database shouldnt be holding numbers with commas. These should be implemented using `number_format()`.

Comment: `$result = intval($a-$b)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments. Your database should only hold the number for example 1000 not 1,000.

here's a code snippet:

```
<?php
$a = 4500;
$b = 5;
$result = $a - $b;
echo number_format($result);
?>
```

This then outputs 4,495

**However here is what you're requesting:**

`intval(str_replace(',', '', $a)) - intval(str_replace(',', '', $b))`

Comment: in my database values has commas. what is the right thing to do about it?

Comment: Your type should be `INT`. What is it currently, Im assuming `VARCHAR` or `TEXT`.